# Open read only workbook for editing

Tags: excel, vba, password-protection

I am trying to automatically update a file on the server that is accessible to everyone as read only. Editing is only for a few people. Therefore, it is password protected, but only for editing and not for opening.

I tried to write a macro to open a password protected file, but that only works for files that are protected against opening. I tried the following code as others suggested it might help to turn of displayalerts and/or ignorereadonly, but that does not help. I keep getting a pop-up that says "Enter password for write access, or open read only". I even tried SendKeys to enter the password, but than the pop-up shows too.

Any suggestions that I might not have though of?

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open Filename:="test.xlsx", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Password:="password", ReadOnly:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim fFilename As String

   fFilename = "C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\test.xlsx"

    SetAttr fFilename, vbNormal

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fFilename, Password:="test")

       wb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
       wb.Close SaveChanges:=True

 ' It will set the File back to Read only   
SetAttr fFilename, vbReadOnly



End Sub
```

Comment: I am looking to open a password secured file in editing mode that is not secured for read-only. If I run this code, I just get the pop-up asking me to enter the password.

Comment: @edgarpiet Now check the code, Hope it works well for you

Comment: I tried this, but it still opens as read-only. I want to automatically enter the password so it opens in editing mode and my macro can change things in the file. After that it needs to be saved under the same name including the password so the rest of the company can view the file in read-only mode without needing a password.

Comment: @edgarpiet I have made changes to open in normal mode, make changes ,close it. Then it make the file access to read only file. Check the code and let me know the result

Comment: mmm, believe it or not, but I still get  a pop-up asking me for the password, despite the application.displayalerts=false.

Comment: Is it asking for password? Did you change the password? Do you have password for sheets also? I have provided password for whole workbook.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but this post helped me figure it out. 
Just add the password for writing to the file.  Add the 
WriteResPassword:="password"
ex: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile, Password:="1234abc", WriteResPassword:="1234abc", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)